# Session Cookie Error in IE11 on first visit only (MVC app)

Tags: session, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, internet-explorer-11

I have a site that performs a session check on '"authLevel"' to display (or not) a link to admin features.

The check:

```
@if (Session["authLevel"].ToString() == "Admin")
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "User_Maintenance", "Admin")</li>
}
```

This works fine in every other browser (chrome, firefox, opera) but the first time I launch the application in IE and try to login (which would create the session) it gives me a null reference error:

```
System.NullReferenceException {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
```

I am setting my session in the controller of every page.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string userName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
            string str = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            User _user = Testing.Models.User.GetById(str);
            Session["empUserId"] = _user.Id;
            Session["displayName"] = _user.UserName;

            if(_user.isAdmin) {
                Session["authLevel"] = "Admin";
            }
            else
            {
                Session["authLevel"] = "User";
            }

        }
```

I haven't got this error in any other browser, but it's important that this application works seamlessly across all browsers.